# How to make Circle with wavy border in Flutter to show Image?

Tags: flutter, mobile

I want to make circle container with wavy border. For that, I used [flutter_custom_clippers 2.0.0](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_custom_clippers) package's **StarClipper** with some changes. But, I can't make it same as I want. Can anyone help?

If any other way is available then please let me know. Thank you in advance :)

Here is my code:

```
import 'dart:math' as math;

import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

/// Clip widget in star shape
class StarClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  StarClipper(this.numberOfPoints);

  /// The number of points of the star
  final int numberOfPoints;

  late int counter = 0;

  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    double width = size.width;

    double halfWidth = width / 2;

    double bigRadius = halfWidth;

    double radius = halfWidth / 1.11;

    double degreesPerStep = _degToRad(360 / numberOfPoints) as double;

    double halfDegreesPerStep = degreesPerStep / 2;

    var path = Path();

    double max = 2 * math.pi;

    path.moveTo(width, halfWidth);

    debugPrint('halfWidth: $halfWidth');
    debugPrint('bigRadius: $bigRadius');
    debugPrint('degreesPerStep: $degreesPerStep');
    debugPrint('max: $max');

    path.moveTo(
      halfWidth + radius * math.cos(0 + halfDegreesPerStep),
      halfWidth + radius * math.sin(0 + halfDegreesPerStep),
    );

    for (double step = 0; step < max + 1; step += degreesPerStep) {
      debugPrint('math.cos(step): ${math.cos(step)}');
      debugPrint('math.sin(step): ${math.sin(step)}');
      debugPrint(
          'math.cos(step + halfDegreesPerStep): ${math.cos(step + halfDegreesPerStep)}');
      debugPrint(
          'math.sin(step + halfDegreesPerStep): ${math.sin(step + halfDegreesPerStep)}');

      debugPrint('------step-------: $step');
      debugPrint('x 1: ${halfWidth + bigRadius * math.cos(step)}');
      debugPrint('y 1: ${halfWidth + bigRadius * math.sin(step)}');
      debugPrint(
          'x 2: ${halfWidth + radius * math.cos(step + halfDegreesPerStep)}');
      debugPrint(
          'y 2: ${halfWidth + radius * math.sin(step + halfDegreesPerStep)}');

      /*path.quadraticBezierTo(
        halfWidth + bigRadius * math.cos(step),
        halfWidth + bigRadius * math.sin(step),
        halfWidth + radius * math.cos(step + halfDegreesPerStep),
        halfWidth + radius * math.sin(step + halfDegreesPerStep),
      );*/

      if (counter % 2 == 0) {
        path.quadraticBezierTo(
          halfWidth + bigRadius * math.cos(step),
          halfWidth + bigRadius * math.sin(step),
          halfWidth + radius * math.cos(step + halfDegreesPerStep),
          halfWidth + radius * math.sin(step + halfDegreesPerStep),
        );
      } else {
        path.quadraticBezierTo(
          halfWidth + radius * math.cos(step),
          halfWidth + radius * math.sin(step),
          halfWidth + bigRadius * math.cos(step + halfDegreesPerStep),
          halfWidth + bigRadius * math.sin(step + halfDegreesPerStep),
        );
      }

      counter++;
    }
    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  num _degToRad(num deg) => deg * (math.pi / 180.0);

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    StarClipper oldie = oldClipper as StarClipper;
    return numberOfPoints != oldie.numberOfPoints;
  }
}
```

Output:

[image]

I want like below

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I achieved it using the same **StarClipper** file of [flutter_custom_clippers 2.0.0 package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_custom_clippers)'s by applying some minor changes in above code.

```
double outerCurveRadius = width / 2.08;
double innerCurveRadius = width / 2.42;
```

```
for (double step = 0; step < max + 1; step += degreesPerStep) {
  if (counter % 2 == 0) {
    path.quadraticBezierTo(
      halfWidth + outerCurveRadius * math.cos(step),
      halfWidth + outerCurveRadius * math.sin(step),
      halfWidth + radius * math.cos(step + halfDegreesPerStep),
      halfWidth + radius * math.sin(step + halfDegreesPerStep),
    );
  } else {
    path.quadraticBezierTo(
      halfWidth + innerCurveRadius * math.cos(step),
      halfWidth + innerCurveRadius * math.sin(step),
      halfWidth + radius * math.cos(step + halfDegreesPerStep),
      halfWidth + radius * math.sin(step + halfDegreesPerStep),
    );
  }

  counter++;
}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check this package [flutter_custom_clippers](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_custom_clippers). I think it's helpful.